# Are there ski resorts that you can drive to in an evening from Atlanta, GA?

Tags: usa, skiing, atlanta, georgia-usa

A friend (not yet on Travel.SE...) has recently moved out to Atlanta, Georgia, and was disappointed to discover quite how far it is from Atlanta to the big-name US ski resorts. (The perils of coming from the UK!)

However, Atlanta is fairly close to the start of the Appalachian mountains, and I believe that there may be some skiing somewhere amongst them!

What I don't know is if any of them are close enough that you could (say) leave work on a Friday, drive, and reach them in an evening. The question therefore is: are there any ski resorts that can be driven to from Atlanta in under 6 hours? Or is my friend's only option going to be to make a long weekend of it, and have to drive a lot further?

Comment: That depends on your definition of a "mountain".  If you're used to skiing in the Alps, then Appalachia will feel like small hills at best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There don't appear to be any ski hills in Georgia, however, [there are a handfull within a ~4 hour drive of Atlanta](http://www.slopequest.com/slopes/southeast/).  I've never been to any of them, though.

Comment: That website is very handy, thanks for the pointer! Looks like [Cloudmont in Alabama](http://www.slopequest.com/slopes/AL/Cloudmont%20Ski%20Resort.html) is only 2.5 hours drive away. Heading north, [Scaly Mountain](http://www.slopequest.com/slopes/NC/Scaly%20Mountain%20Ski%20Area.html) in NC is 2.5 hours drive, and then there's several more past there!

Comment: Keep in mind that not all locations allow for skiing (even if they have skiing in their name).  For example, [Scaly Mountain](http://www.scalymountain.com/) appears to only have snow tubing.  Also, both of the places you mention aren't really "mountains"; they only have a ~200 foot vertical drop, which is *very* short for skiing.